Unsupported Video format instagram graph API
I Am trying to upload Reels from a business Instagram account for that i already have access token and long lived token.The problem is that whenever i try to publish a reel it gives me "The video file you selected is in a format that we don't support." error code:352 and error_subcode:2207026.I have also converted that video but its saying the same.But I am able to upload a video of "640x480" but not any other resolution like 720x1280 etc. The url of video is aws
I have tried converting video using ffmpeg but it gives me aspect ratio error on 720x1280 whether its 9:16 or 16:9 when i try to upload video of like 1080x1920 it gives me streams error i have also added validation in my uploadReel function and funtion return true but still i am getting video format not supported error
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import axios from 'axios';
import asyncHandler from '../../../middlewares/asyncHandler';
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg';
import ffmpegInstaller from '@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg';

ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegInstaller.path);

export const uploadReel = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { longLivedToken, videoUrl }: any = req.body;

  if (!longLivedToken || !videoUrl) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid data' });
  }

  console.log('Checking video format for:', videoUrl);

  // Check if the video has supported codecs (H.264 for video and AAC for audio)
  ffmpeg(videoUrl).ffprobe((err, metadata) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error reading video metadata:', err.message);
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Unable to check video metadata or invalid file.' });
    }

    console.log('Video metadata:', JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 2));

    const hasValidCodec = metadata.streams.some(
      (stream: any) => stream.codec_name === 'h264' && stream.codec_type === 'video'
    ) && metadata.streams.some(
      (stream: any) => stream.codec_name === 'aac' && stream.codec_type === 'audio'
    );

    if (!hasValidCodec) {
      console.error('Unsupported file format. Expected H.264 video codec and AAC audio codec.');
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'Unsupported file format. Ensure the video is in MP4 format with H.264 video codec and AAC audio codec.',
      });
    }

    console.log('Video format is supported. Proceeding with upload.');

    // If format is supported, proceed to upload the video
    axios.post(
      `https://graph.instagram.com/v20.0/me/media`,
      {
        media_type: 'REELS',
        video_url: videoUrl, // Publicly accessible URL of the video file
        access_token: longLivedToken,
      },
      {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      }
    )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Reel successfully uploaded:', response.data);
        return res.status(200).json({ mediaId: response.data.id });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error uploading reel:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to upload reel' });
      });
  });
});


export const publishReel = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { mediaId, longLivedToken }: any = req.body;

  if (!mediaId || !longLivedToken) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid data' });
  }

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `https://graph.instagram.com/v20.0/me/media_publish`,
      {
        creation_id: mediaId,
        access_token: longLivedToken,
      },
      {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      }
    );

    return res.status(200).json({ postId: response.data.id }); // Return post ID
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error publishing image:', error.response ? error.response.data : error.message)}
    
});



enter image description here`

Having same issue
{
"error": {
"message": "The video file you selected is in a format that we don't support.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 352,
"error_subcode": 2207026,
"is_transient": false,
"error_user_title": "Unsupported format",
"error_user_msg": "The video format is not supported. Please check spec for supported aspect_ratio format",
"fbtrace_id": "AHQFeDkuE6rhTYZ8YGoQtBa"
}
}

Facing same issue, Here's my video details
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'H4sIAAAAAAAAAxXTBw0AQQwDQUpplwInlT-E1yPwaiTrsdMAkajYSCZ2CZI-azCq0xAHA39ylA9Pd5kmGlb6YfsYDTNFYrxRf-U-GlgaN4PJCTuLjuOCholi7-kruX7RU4cSSo7LYPx0a2A4StDs0KQSQ-9OpeskkEyuXhpgBGczlU27Dwa7qf55wDbhCHZOgMOdnkk0a0nB0geksnUWGLGTVPNaH69oAZe2Hv8lYtEp.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : isom
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
comment         : vid:v12044gd0000cjq6p9jc77u6b3hnu51g
aigc_info       : {"aigc_label_type": 0}
encoder         : Lavf58.76.100
Duration: 00:00:58.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 991 kb/s
Stream #0:00x1: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 576x1024 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 953 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandler
vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream #0:10x2: Audio: aac (HE-AACv2) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 32 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandler
vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]

Facing the same issue with videos matching perfectly the specs: https://storage.googleapis.com/klap-assets/output_8.mp4
ffprobe version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
configuration: --prefix=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-neon
libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://storage.googleapis.com/klap-assets/output_8.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand     : mp42
minor_version   : 512
compatible_brands: mp42iso2avc1mp41
encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
comment         : Made with Remotion 4.0.160
Duration: 00:00:59.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4339 kb/s
Stream #0:00x1: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1080x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 9:16], 4203 kb/s, 29.99 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : VideoHandler
vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libx264
Stream #0:10x2: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, mono, fltp, 129 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
handler_name    : SoundHandler
vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
